# KSQL is failing with CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character when reading stream

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm streaming some data into Kafka using Kafka Connect. I'm able to view this data using `print 'kdc-01-orders' from beginning;`. The data looks to be correct JSON. Just to make sure, I parsed it as JSON successfully.

So I created a table using that topic like this:

```
create table orders
(order_num varchar, cust_id integer, order_date integer)
with
(kafka_topic='kdc-01-orders', value_format='json', key='order_num');
```

The table is created successfully. However, when I query it like this:

```
select * from orders limit 100;
```

I see lots of errors in the ksql log. They look like this:

```
ksql-server_1      | [2019-07-01 21:21:43,803] WARN task [0_0] Skipping record due to deserialization error. topic=[kdc-01-orders] partition=[0] offset=[999] (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer:86)
ksql-server_1      | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: KsqlJsonDeserializer failed to deserialize data for topic: kdc-01-orders
ksql-server_1      | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: 
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:334)
ksql-server_1      |    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.json.KsqlJsonDeserializer.getGenericRow(KsqlJsonDeserializer.java:80)
ksql-server_1      |    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.json.KsqlJsonDeserializer.deserialize(KsqlJsonDeserializer.java:67)
ksql-server_1      |    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.json.KsqlJsonDeserializer.deserialize(KsqlJsonDeserializer.java:37)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:58)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:60)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.maybeUpdateTimestamp(RecordQueue.java:160)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:101)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:124)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:711)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:995)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:833)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
ksql-server_1      | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x1a9ef2e (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7)
ksql-server_1      | Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x1a9ef2e (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7)
ksql-server_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.reportInvalid(UTF32Reader.java:195)
ksql-server_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.read(UTF32Reader.java:158)
ksql-server_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._loadMore(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:243)
ksql-server_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2331)
ksql-server_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:646)
ksql-server_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4042)
ksql-server_1      |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2571)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:50)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:332)
ksql-server_1      |    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.json.KsqlJsonDeserializer.getGenericRow(KsqlJsonDeserializer.java:80)
ksql-server_1      |    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.json.KsqlJsonDeserializer.deserialize(KsqlJsonDeserializer.java:67)
ksql-server_1      |    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.json.KsqlJsonDeserializer.deserialize(KsqlJsonDeserializer.java:37)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:58)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:60)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.maybeUpdateTimestamp(RecordQueue.java:160)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:101)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:124)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:711)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:995)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:833)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
ksql-server_1      |    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
```

The character in question, `0x1a9ef2e`, doesn't seem to be a valid character, like the error says. This data is pulled from a database with a latin1 encoding, but I'm not sure how to tell this to KSQL. This error was repeated many times, each time with a different character.

Answer (score 2):

The PRINT command will also output Avro records to look like JSON.  However, PRINT also outputs the *format* of the value (and key) at the topic.  Check this to see if the data is actually JSON or AVRO:

```
    Key format: KAFKA_STRING
    Value format: AVRO
    rowtime: 12/21/18 23:58:42 PM PSD, key: k0, value: {"v0":"hello": "v1": 10}
    ^CTopic printing ceased
```

This post goes into converters and serialization in more depth: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/